# glMultiDrawArraysIndirect and trying to find which draw call it is

Tags: opengl

So I have one huge VBO where all my models are stored, and a bunch of draw calls ready to submit to glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.

I also have a uniform block full of matrices so ship A goes to position A, ship B goes to position B, etc.

My question is - how does one make glsl aware which draw call is which? I tried changing the baseInstance variable but that doesn't seem to affect gl_InstanceID, which also starts at 0 for every draw call. After reading further on the khronos page, it seems like this variable won't affect anything.

So what is the proper way to include matrices so each draw call draws things at different positions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GL 4.6/ARB_shader_draw_parameters, then you have [access to `gl_DrawID`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs), which is exactly what it sounds like: the zero-based index of the draw in any multi-draw command. It's also guaranteed to be [dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression), so you can use it to access texture arrays (that is, `sampler2D texarray[5];`, not `sampler2DArray texarray;`) and other things that require dynamically uniform values.

If you don't... then your best bet is to create an [instance array](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instance_Array) that contains indices, starting with 0. Your VS will have an input corresponding to this value. `gl_InstanceID` is not affected by the base instance, but the value fetched from an instance array *is* affected by it. So it will give you a proper index, at the cost of having a seemingly pointless value lying around.

Also, such a value will not be dynamically uniform. But that's usually not a big deal. It's only a problem if you want to access texture arrays.